# Unable to resolve XXX from module YYY

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

I’m building a small app that fetch contents from an API, some of the content is in HTML and i’m willing to display it in HTML (basic tags, like B, I, P and so on). I tried to use `react-native-render-html` and it also requires `react-native-webview` (which I also installed)
but when starting the expo server with the following include

```
import { HTML } from 'react-native-render-html';
```

i got the following error:

> **Unable to resolve “./MultiplexHandler” from "node_modules\htmlparser2\lib\CollectingHandler.js"**

and in fact `MultiplexHandler.js` is missing from `node_modules\htmlparser2\lib\`.

At the moment im using:

```
"react-native-render-html": "^4.2.2-beta.2",
"react-native-webview": "^10.3.2"
```

Any help would be appreciated, even on alternative way to display a little of HTML text,
Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a link [to a snack](https://snack.expo.io/) which reproduces this error?

Comment: Also, please note that the kind of context which would be helpful relates to your building environment (OS, npm or yarn ... etc), rather than the specifics of what you are trying to achieve in your app, which is irrelevant here.

I tried to reproduce your issue on a fresh install, and I couldn't. But I am using npm and Linux. Also tried in a snack with no success. If the answer I gave bellow didn't help you, you could try a new snack [from our template](https://snack.expo.io/@jsamr/rnrhtml-template), and iteratively add one of the dependencies you use to see if it breaks.

Comment: Could you resolve your issue? Please help me helping the community :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Take #1, metro

This is probably an issue with metro bundler after you've just added a new dependency. Try restarting with a clean cache:

```sh
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Or if you're using expo

```sh
expo start --clear
```

Also, take notice that working on Windows
[can cause problems](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/181).

### Take #2, dependencies

The other track would be an issue with yarn or npm. To play it safe, you can do the following in a clean directory (you have committed your changes to whichever CVS you're using):

1. Delete `node_modules`.
2. Delete your lock file, either `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`.
3. Perform a fresh install, either `npm install` or `yarn install`.

Comment: With a fresh start and module cleaning i was able to solve it